# How to save output of a magic function (like %hist) into a text file?

Tags: python, ipython

So I really need to restore what I did in ipython about a month ago. I figured out that I need to use %hist -g command. However output is too big to read in shell. How do I save the output?

I've tried to save the output into a variable, with an intention to write it into a text file, like so:

```
myhist = %hist -g
```

But it does not work, it seems like function does not `return` anything, only prints.

So is there a way to access the history in some manageable ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use command `history` and give a filename as argument.

```
%history [-n] [-o] [-p] [-t] [-f FILENAME] [-g [PATTERN [PATTERN ...]]]
             [-l [LIMIT]] [-u]
             [range [range ...]]
```

Example:

```
%history -g -f file.txt
```

Check out official reference [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-history)

Answer (score 1):

```
%hist -g -f FILENAME
```

Note that the file is always overwritten without confirmation if exists.